# Align icons vertically in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, bottomnavigationview

In short, I don't want the empty space below the icons of bottom navigation view. Here is how it looks.

[Screenshot with layout bounds enabled in developer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83YUS.jpg)

[Screenshot without layout bounds enabled in developer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF08b.jpg)

This is what I have done in MainActivity layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Breathe"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainFrag" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:gravity="center">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is what I have done on the Java side:

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                Log.d("Dark Mode","Dark mode");
                shape =  new GradientDrawable();
                shape.setCornerRadius( 40 );
                shape.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                bottomNavigationView.setBackground(shape);  

                break;
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                Log.d("Light Mode","Light mode");
                shape =  new GradientDrawable();
                shape.setCornerRadius( 40);
                shape.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                bottomNavigationView.setBackground(shape);
                break;
        }
```

I have used java to set the shape drawable so as to implement light/dark theme based on system settings.

I have tried padding, it works but then the layout of the icons messes up on smaller display sizes. I am hoping there's another way to do it.

Comment: I think the bottom navigation is saving space for the title of each button. Have you looked into the possibility of disabling titles? Oops. I just read the option "unlabeled" on the xml.

Comment: @Lheonair haha :") Do you have any clue what it might be? I made it xml only and still it's still having the same issue,

Comment: Have you tried center vertical gravity attribute? I suppose you could also put the BottomNavigationView inside a ConstraintLayout and constrain it to the parent's top and bottom?

Comment: @nicoqueijo It was something to do with the system navigation bar padding interfering with the sticky immersive mode. Tweaking it a bit fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the bottom navigation view conflicting somehow with the sticky immersive mode. Changing the way how I achieved full screen solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's an old question.
For those that still encounter this. The problem is that on older phones with system built-in bottom navigation bar

like this

[image: 1]

the system does NOT render correctly BottomNavigationView if the system navigation bar is transparent.

So **quick fix**: If your system navigation bar is transparent (from the Themes.xml or programtically) change it to solid and it should fix it.